# Can I parameterize a Slick query macro?

Tags: scala, slick

In Slick, one can write a query in a macro, and it is transformed in a pretty good query, with a type, e.g. like this: `db.run(sql"""SELECT COUNT(1) FROM myTable""")`

But is there a way to pass the table name in a parameter, like this:

```
  val tableName = "myTable"
  db.run(sql"""SELECT COUNT(1) FROM $tableName""")
```

I tried, and all I see is the query transforming to `"SELECT COUNT(1) FROM $1"` which probably hints to the need to provide the table name as a statement parameter - but how? Nothing in the docs.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `#` in front of a variable that should not be "interpreted":

```scala
val tableName = "myTable"
db.run(sql"""SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #$tableName""")
```

See the documentation: https://scala-slick.org/doc/devel/sql.html#splicing-literal-values